# mongo convert field to NumberLong

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

In mongo I want to convert for docs in a collection:

```
{   
 "timestamp" : 1494624438268.0
}
```

to

```
{    
"timestamp" : NumberLong(1494624438268)
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Don't know what exactly you are looking for ...Here's a link for ur help :
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/shell-types/#numberlong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found it

```
db.getCollection('collection-name').find().limit(10).forEach(function(data) {
if (data.timestamp instanceof NumberLong === false) {
    data.timestamp=NumberLong(data.timestamp);});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to select your document and then update with the corresponding type.

```
db.collection.updateOne( { timestamp: 1494624438268.0 }, { $set:  { timestamp: NumberLong("1494624438268") } } )
```

Comment: i want to iterate and do it for all records in the collection.